# Python: Scheduling an Airflow dag to run twice (n times) a day at random?

Tags: python, airflow

How can I configure my dag to run twice a day (or n times) daily, and if possible with some required buffer of time between runs (for example each run must come at least 6 hours after the most recent dag run).

I know at an abstract level I may need to do something like this:

```
import random
 
schedule=f"{random.randint(0,59)} {random.randint(0,24)} * * *"
```

I just don't know how to enforce the twice a day requirement (or time buffer)?

Answer (score 0):

**1. n runs a day**

- `schedule_interval` [can be](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/scheduling-tasks/) a `timedelta` object; citing the [docstring](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/37798f0d2a91eeaca5e816b63beac44d3c0898aa/airflow/models/dag.py#L108)

> ```
> :param schedule_interval: Defines how often that DAG runs, this
>         timedelta object gets added to your latest task instance's
>         execution_date to figure out the next schedule
> :type schedule_interval: datetime.timedelta or
>         dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta or str that acts as a cron
>         expression
> ```

- So with 1440 minutes in a day and 'n' runs, you can put `schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(minutes=(1440/n))`

**2. randomization**

- randomization bit is not clear;

  - with 'n' runs per day, how do you want to fit-in *randomization*?

Comment: By randomization I simply mean that I want to run the dag twice a day, but have those run times be random (not hard-coded times)

Comment: but with a certain minimum gap (time-interval) between consecutive runs, right? That interval must be enforced across runs within a single day (b/w 00:00 hours and 23:59 hours) or should it also hold across consecutive runs spanning across two dates?

Comment: That interval just needs to hold across consecutive runs if possible